# Add TinyMCE to CPT metaboxes in 3.1?

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, tinymce, wysiwyg

Been looking around for an alternative to this method:
http://allcreatives.net/2011/02/02/using-the-native-wordpress-tinymce-wysiwyg-editor-with-your-custom-post-meta-textareas/

To add the WYSIWYG capability to custom metaboxes. You get so little control with this method, is there any other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this class: http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/p/meta-box-script-for-wordpress.html

and then call the metabox like this (don't forget to read the manual and view some examples):

```
$meta_boxes[] = array(
    'id' => 'textmetabox',
    'title' => 'Your Meta Box Title',
    'pages' => array('post', 'slider', 'whatever-your-cpt-is'),

    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'Your thoughts about Deluxe Blog Tips',
            'id' => $prefix . 'thoughts',
            'type' => 'wysiwyg',
            'std' => '<b>It\'s great!</b>',
            'desc' => 'Do you think so?',
            'style' => 'width: 300px; height: 400px'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks, works great! Although do you think it's possible to have different sets of button for each WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: @Daniel Sachs and INT , I'm using the same script and looking into adding different buttons to each WYSIWYG editor that appear on the same page. Do you know if it's possible? :) thanks

Answer (score -1):

The above meta box script is no longer working in WP 3.2. The WYSIWYG editor is display in white background and the buttons are all gone!

Anyone has solution for this problem in 3.2 ?

Comment: Firstly, do not answer questions with a question. You should create a new question since this question specifically is for 3.1

Comment: Check out [22599](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22599/wordpress-3-2-has-broken-my-tinymce-code) for info on 3.2 WYSIWYG changes.