# Setting a Master Menu on a Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, menus

I am currently developing a site for a car dealership to list their inventory. I have setup the car up as a custom post type. Each post will have children (gallery, features, accessories, etc).

I want to have a nav on all of the pages like so:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/ford-escape-lt/gallery/">Gallery</a>
    <li><a href="/ford-escape-lt/features/">Features</a>
    <li><a href="/ford-escape-lt/accessories/">Accessories</a>
</ul>
```

It would be nice to just create a single template like single-car.php and then have the menu in there. The question is, how do I replace the first part of the menu (/ford-escape-lt) with the current page we are on? Is there any way to add classes to the current page item?

Comment: Hi and welcome :) Please, add the PHP code that will render that Html output. Create your `single-car.php` based on `single.php`, locate the [relevant code](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu), do your tests and update the Question.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar, and here's how I handled it.

First off, instead of using child pages, I put all the data on one page, and I stored the would-be "children" as postmeta. My custom post type editing page had 7 or 8 editors in it. This kept the WordPress admin cleaner and it made it easier to edit my posts, since I didn't start the post in one place then have to create 7 more pages and edit them. I won't include that code, as it's covered well [elsewhere](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21641/add-tinymce-to-cpt-metaboxes-in-3-1).

I navigated the page through rewrite tags. Here is what was in my functions.php file for this (all sample code modified for your data):

```
add_action('init', 'wpse_74829_rewrite_additions');
function wpse_74829_rewrite_additions() {
    add_rewrite_tag( '%section%', '(gallery|features|accessories)' );
    add_rewrite_rule('^([^/]+)/(gallery|features|accessories)/?', 'index.php?car=$matches[1]&section=$matches[2]', 'top');
}
```

Next, I had a helper to display the content depending on the section.

```
<?php
function wpse_74829_the_section( $section ) {
    $content = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), $section, true );
    if ( $content ) {
        $content = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $content );
        echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
    }
}
?>
```

And here's what the inside of my loop looked like, with regards to the content:

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <?php
    switch ( $wp_query->query_vars['section'] ) {
        case 'gallery':
            wpse_74829_the_section( 'gallery' );
            break;

        case 'features':
            wpse_74829_the_section( 'features' );
            break;

        case 'accessories':
            wpse_74829_the_section( 'accessories' );
            break;

        default:
            the_content();
            break;
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Lastly, I had a helper for my links:

```
function wpse_74829_the_section_url( $section ) {
    $url = get_permalink();
    if ( strpos( $url, '?') ) echo add_query_arg( 'section', $section );
    else echo $url . $section . '/';
}
```

And then I could link to the sections within the page like,
`<?php wpse_74829_the_section_url( 'gallery' ); ?>`